# Loopback (DB2) - Can not create an instance of PersistedModel that uses a schema other than the userid

Tags: db2, loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to define a model that is based on the PersistedModel to access a table in DB2, call it `MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE`.

I created the model `MY_TABLE`, based on PersistedModel, with a Data Source (`datasources.json`) where the definition includes the attribute `"schema": "MY_SCHEMA"`.  The data source also contains the userid `my_userid`, used for the connection.

### Current Behavior

When I try to call the API for this model, it tries to access the table `my_userid.MY_TABLE`.

### Expected Behavior

It should access `MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE`.

The DB2 instance happens to be on a System Z.  I have created a table called `my_userid.MY_TABLE` and that will work, however for the solution we are trying to build, there are multiple schemas required.

Note that this only appears to be an issue with Db2 on System Z.  I can change schemas on Db2 LUW.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions?

Answer (score 0):

What LoopBack connector are you using? What version? Can you also check what version of `loopback-ibmdb` is installed in your `node_modules` folder?

AFAICT, LoopBack's DB2-related connectors support `schema` field, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-ibmdb/blob/master/lib/ibmdb.js#L96-L100

```
self.schema = this.username;
if (settings.schema) {
  self.schema = settings.schema.toUpperCase();
}

self.connStr += ';CurrentSchema=' + self.schema;
```

Have you considered configuring the database connection using `DSN` instead of individual fields like `hostname` and `username`?

In your datasource config JSON:

```
"dsn": "DATABASE={dbname};HOSTNAME={hostname};UID={username};PWD={password};CurrentSchema=MY_SCHEMA"
```